# What is the pythonic way of doing a for loop with these conditions "built in"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a class method I have the following:

```
if self.zot == 1:
        for foo in self.bar:
            if self.zot != 1:
                break
            #code that may or may not change self.zot
```

`bar` is a property that I'd rather not access and populate unless absolutely necessary, so if `zot` isn't 1 I'd still like to prevent that first iteration.

Python being python I'm guessing there's still a way cleaner way to do this.

Something like the following?

```
for foo in self.bar while self.zot == 1:
```

Bonus points for an answer compatible with python 2.7.x

EDIT: Whether `zot` is modified during the iteration is partially independent of `bar`'s contents so `takewhile` is impractical. Either way `bar` needs to not be accessed in the first place if `zot` isn't 1.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Your `for` loop only implements if `self.zot==1`, then why do you need to check `self.zot` again in the third line? It will never be true.

Comment: @LongwenOu the code beyond line 4 within the for loop might change the value of zot. Iteration beyond that point needs to cease.

Comment: @LongwenOu I believe OP wants to have a `for` loop (with all its iterator goodies) with some `while` semantics to additionally check for `self.zot == 1` and one way to do this is to check before and in the loop

Comment: To be clear: merely accessing `self.bar` is already an expensive operation, as `bar` is a `property` or some other descriptor, with an expensive getter, right?

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal As you can see in the documentation for [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) as the answer suggests, it would start iterating over `self.bar`, as the predicate checks the elements of the iterated object, not a free-standing condition

Comment: I don't think there's anything cleaner than what you already have.

Comment: @user2357112 Correct, edited my question to clarify. Thanks for looking. :)

Comment: you _could_ move the `zot` check into property `bar`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `for` into a `while` loop and use `iter()` and `next()`, although it is not very pythonic and would require using a `try except`.

```
iterator = None
while self.zot == 1:
    iterator = iterator or iter(self.bar)
    try:
        current = iterator.next()
        #your code
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This will start using `self.bar` only when you go into the `while` for the first time.

You may create a proxy function to delegate the check.

```
def check_and_iterate(iterable, predicate):
    i = None
    while predicate():
        i = i or iter(iterable)
        yield i.next()

for foo in check_and_iterate(self.bar, lambda: self.zot == 1):
    #your code
```

EDIT:
As @user2357112 pointed out, `self.bar` is accessed anyway. You can defer it by using another lambda:

```
def check_and_iterate(getter, predicate):
    i = None
    while predicate():
        i = i or iter(getter())
        yield i.next()

for foo in check_and_iterate(lambda: self.bar, lambda: self.zot == 1):
    #your code
```

Comment: Your `check_and_iterate` snippet accesses `self.bar` unconditionally, so it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, with property `bar` handling the `zot` checking

```
@property
def bar(self):
    itr = iter(self._bar)
    while self.zot == 1:
        yield next(itr)
```

Comment: For my case, bar is accessed in other contexts that aren't zot-dependent.

Comment: yeah, then just add a different property that does this